# Grouping with if condition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've got a table with a number of rows. Let's say it has 2 columns called Value and Value Type. I've got a group on Value Type

Outside the group, I've got 2 rows. 1 for each value type (There's only 2 value types). I want to sum the values for each value type, but the issue appears that I can't reference more than one column.

So I can't do something like this as it's referencing two fields.
=SUM(IIF(Fields!ValueType.Value="Blah",Fields!Value.Value,0))

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just needed to use the phase Nothing, rather than 0.